# card-deck, "Deck not defined" node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, I am progressing in making a card game in Discord with Javascript/node.js. I have been messing with this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/card-deck) in the RunKit just to try and get a basic understanding before using it with my code. Perhaps call me totally inexperienced, but I get the result below when running the code displayed in the image.

https://i.gyazo.com/72da331f99b77afe425c132bacec8078.png

I also tried it in VSC, after installing as they recommend, to get the same result. I noticed that card-deck is on the older side (3 years old on last update) so I don't know if something is outdated and that is why it isn't working, or I am completely missing something.

Any advice? I need the card/deck handling to be able to require various piles/objects. Discard pile, active cards, hand, side decks, ect... and be able to move cards to and from them after originating in a "main deck". Any advice on what went wrong or advice on where to start would be great. Thanks.

Comment: *code in image* is useless. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should not post images of code. Code is written in text, and can be copied/pasted directly into your post here. See [ask] and [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Apologies. I usually don't post images of code like that. Since I was using RunKit, I wanted to provide everything I saw so I figured an image would give a better idea of what I was seeing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try renaming the variable `cardDeck` into `var Deck = require('card-deck')` instead. That way the variable `Deck` will be defined. Also surround the cards with single quotes like this:

```
['h4', 's2']
```

Comment: That was totally the problem. In RunKit, it had it defined as (Var cardDeck) by default which I'm unsure why it was like that instead of "Deck". I only added the last 2 lines. But it looks to be working properly in RunKit and in my code in VSC. Thanks!